# React hook array first value empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await, react-hooks

I am trying to save an array which I fetch from an api and save it to `useState([''])`, doing this my first entry inside my array is empty.

It looks like this:
`(3) ["", "5ea5d29230778c1cd47e02dd", "5ea5d2f430778c1cd47e02de"]`

The actual data which I get from my axios call it this `(2) ["5ea5d29230778c1cd47e02dd", "5ea5d2f430778c1cd47e02de"]`

This is how I call it and set it:

```
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(['']);

  const getIds = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/favIds');
    setFavorites(favorites => [...favorites, ...data.favorites]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getIds();
  }, []);
```

**Edit**

I am using typescript

IF I set it up like this:

`const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]);`

I get this error:

```
> Argument of type '(favorites: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.   Type '(favorites:
> never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) =>
> never[]'.
>     Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
>       Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: `...favorites`. Your appending to the existing array that you have `''` already.  Any reason why you init the array with `''`?

Comment: @Keith it does not work in typescript if it is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define its type like this:

```
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState<string[]>([]);


  setFavorites(() => [...data.favorites])
```

Comment: I think just using setFavorites([...data.favourites]), since it is using hooks @utdev

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the type of useState to be `string[]`

```
const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const getIds = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/favIds');
    setFavorites(favorites => [...favorites, ...data.favorites]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getIds();
  }, []);
```

[Sample demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-tereshkova-sjl6s?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: ohh yeah, I focussed on the error and so completely missed the initial state

Answer (score 0):

The first element is actually your default state here: `useState([''])`. 
You initialized it with an empty string as a value, and you spread it into the new state in your `[...favorites, ...data.favorites]` codeblock.

Change your init state declaration to `useState([])`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep that empty string value or not?

If you don't, you don't need to include what was in the state before when you add the data you get with axios:

```
setFavorites(() => [...data.favorites])
```