# Empty first element custom component array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a simple resume app where you can add modules (experience, certification) to sections such as education and work. There's an array to store these modules that is set with a hook `const [components, setComponents] = useState([])`. I'm aware that initializing components in this way add a first empty element. What's confusing is that even though I followed the documentation https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state and some other tutorials that points out the same implementation, my first element is not overwritten by the hook when I call it inside a method. I also had a look at this Stackoverflow answer [React hook array first value empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656288/react-hook-array-first-value-empty), which seems to be the closest one to the solution I'm looking for, but still I don't really understand how hooks update arrays.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import Certification from "./certification";
import Experience from "./experience";
import Modules from "./modules";

export default function Section (props){
  const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);
  const [component, setComponent] = useState();

  function addComponent(title){
    
    setComponent();
    switch(title){
      case "Education":
        setComponent(<Certification/>);
        break;
      case "Work":
        setComponent(<Experience/>);
        break; 
      default:
        throw new Error (`Invalid panel type`);
    }

    setComponents([...components, component]);
  }


  function removeComponent(){
    setComponents([...components.slice(0, components.length-1)])
  }

    return(
      <div className="section">
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <button onClick={()=>{addComponent(props.title)}}>Add</button>
        <button onClick={()=>{removeComponent()}}>Remove</button>
        <Modules modules={components}/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm missing/doing wrong in my code please?

Cheers!

Comment: `setComponent` doesn't **do** anything; you're passing nothing to it, so it received an `undefined`. It's not at all clear what `setComponent` is for--why can't you just have the array of components?

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton! Well I'm using a switch inside a funciton add component that assigns useState according to the title of the section. It's sort of a facotry pattern that outputs a different custom component depending on a given input. Thing is that I'm not able to declare `const [component, setComponent]` inside the switch statement cause React works in a different way my editor says. Taking out the switch of `addComponent` throws `Too many renders` exception

Comment: But `setComponent` isn't **needed** (or particularly useful). In any case: setting state is asynchronous; `component` will not be set by the time you call `setComponents`. Why can't you just have a local `component` variable and use that in the call to `setComponents`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @DaveNewton! Storing it in just a variable is the answer. Pointing out that setting state is asynchronous made sense to me. Will put your suggestion as an answer to the question. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so @DaveNewton helped out finding out the problem. I don't actually need to use a hook for assigning custom components inside my switch statement. A variable will do basically.

```
export default function Section (props){
  const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);
  let component;
  function addComponent(title){
    switch(title){
      case "Education":
        component = <Certification/>;
        break;
      case "Work":
        component = <Experience/>;
        break; 
      default:
        throw new Error (`Invalid panel type`);
    }
    setComponents([...components, component]);
  }
}
```